# $f_n(x)= f(x+n)$ show that the limit function is uniformly continuous

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity, sequence-of-function

Let $f$ be a real-valued continuous function on $I=\{x\in \mathbb{R} | x \geq 0\}$. For a positive integer $n$ the function on $I$ is defined by
\begin{align*}f_n(x)= f(x+n)\end{align*}
Answer the following questions when the sequence of functions $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges uniformly on $I$

1. The function $g$ on $I$ is defined by $g(x)=\lim _{n\xrightarrow{}{}\infty}f_n(x)$, show that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $I$
2. show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I$

Here we need to show that $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ for all $x,y\in I$. Since $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ coverge uniformly to $g$ we have $|f_n{(x)}-g(x)|<\epsilon \implies |f(x+n)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$. How do we proceed from here.

Any hints or a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: @zkutch There is no other date about $g$

Comment: @zkutch $f(x) = \sin 2 \pi x$, $f_n (x) = \sin ( 2 \pi x + 2 \pi n) = f(x)$

Comment: @AHusain Since $f(x+n)=f_n(x)$ is continuous if $\forall c \in I$, $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall x\in I$  we have $|f_n(x)-f_n(c)|<\epsilon/3$ whenever $|x-c|<\delta$ and since $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $g(x)$ $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists $ a positive integer $N$ s.t $n\geq N \implies |f_n(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon/3 \forall x\in I$ then $|g(x)-g(y)|= |g(x)+f_n(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(y)-f_n(y)-g(y)|$. Now we have $|g(x)-g(y)|\leq |f_n(x)-g(x)| + |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f_n(y)-g(y)|$. We can substitute $\epsilon/3$ for both $|f_n(x)-g(x)| $ and $|f_n(y)-g(y)|$, but how do we >>>>

Comment: use continuity to get an expression for $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|$?

Comment: @AHusain.  These days your example worried me, and just now I felt what was the matter. If a periodic function has a limit at infinity, then it is constant - isn't it? Thus, your example is not correct and will not work in this situation. What I wrote remains valid: if exists limit then $g(x)=\lim f_n(x)=\lim f(n+x)=\lim f(x)=\text{Const}$.

Comment: Is this marked homework or something else?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh It is an MSC entrance past paper question I start a bounty with the professor's hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints

For (1):
If $f_n\in C({\Bbb R})$, $n\geq 1$ is any uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions, then the limit function $g$ is continuous (proof by an $\epsilon/3$-argument). This is usually part of standard undergraduate curriculum.

Look at the very definitions of $g(x)$ and $g(x+1)$ (for any fixed $x\in {\Bbb R}$) and realize that the values must be the same.
Thus, $g$ is a 1-periodic continuous function.
Conclude from this (using e.g. a compactness argument) that $g$ is uniformly continuous.

For (2): Given $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ so that $|g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon/3$ for $x\geq N$. Using that $g$ is uniformly continuous show there is $\delta_1$ so that $x,y\geq N, |x-y|<\delta_1 \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Show that there is $\delta_2>0$ so that $0\leq x,y\leq N+1, |x-y|<\delta_2 \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Finally, pick $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,1\}$ and conclude.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. In (1) to show that $g$ is 1-periodic,  $g(x)= \lim_{n\xrightarrow{}{}\infty} f_n(x)= \lim_{n\xrightarrow{}{}\infty} f(x+n)$ and $g(x+1)= \lim_{n\xrightarrow{}{}\infty} f_n(x+1) = \lim_{n\xrightarrow{}{}\infty} f(x+1+n)$, are these limits same? Why they should be same?

Comment: Think of what it means to take limits of integer sequences: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)  You may e.g. set $m=n+1$. Then $m\to +\infty$ iff $n\to +\infty$ (as integer sequences) and then $\lim_{n\to +\infty} f(x+n+1)=\lim_{m\to +\infty} f(x+m)$.

Comment: Got it thanks, in (2) what is the first inequality, how do we get it?

Comment: Since $g$ is 1-periodic you may set $x=n+t$ and intepret it as $|g(n+t)-f(n+t)|=|g(t)-f(n+t)|<\epsilon/3$ for $t\in I$ which is a consequence of the unif conv of $f_n(x)$ towards $g(t)$  for $t\in I$

Comment: Arigato Gozaimasu !

Comment: @Priya You are wellcome. Good luck with the entrance-exam